# Submit button works only once on mobile

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm using phonegap to create an application the submit button works just as intended (not refreshing the page) on the browser but when I run it on mobile it works only once, if I press the"Go" button on mobile keyboard it works as intended just the actual submit button isn't working.

not sure if you need more information I could provide more on the code if you'd like.

**JQuery I'm using:**

```js
$(function() {
    $("form").submit(function() { return false; });
});
```

```html
The submit button I'm using 

  <input id="button" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Check" onclick = "check();">
```

```js
// The check function
var correct = 0;
function check (){
    var answer = document.quiz.question1.value;
    var answerL = answer.toLowerCase();
    //var areEqual = question1.toUpperCase() === questions[pos][1].toUpperCase();
    if (answerL !=null && answerL !== ''){
    if (answerL == questions[pos][1]){
        //$(".test").show();
        
        $("#result").attr("src","correct.png");
        $(".correct_answer").css("visibility", "visible");
       
        correct++;
        //delete questions[pos];
        questions.splice(pos, 1);
        var max = questions.length -1;
        //window.prompt(questions); //testing the array deletion
        pos = Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length);
        
        
    document.getElementById("number_correct").className = "green";
    
    }

    else {
        correct--;
        document.getElementById("number_correct").className = "red";
        $("#result").attr("src","wrong.png");
        $(".correct_answer").css("visibility", "visible");
      
    }

}
//$(".correct_answer").css("visibility", "hidden");
questioner ();

    
    document.getElementById("number_correct").innerHTML = "Your Score: " + correct;
    document.getElementById("after_submit").style.visibility = "visible";
    $('#quiz')[0].reset();
    
}

            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  questioner();
});
```

Comment: remove `onclick=check()` and add `check()` right before `return false` in your onsubmit function.

Comment: The page is constantly getting refreshed now whenever I click on submit or enter which I don't want it to do.

Comment: please share check function code as well

Comment: @Alaa - sounds like you added it before `$("form")` instead of immediately before `return false`. should be `$("form").submit(function() { check(); return false; });`

Comment: Occam meant like this: `$(function() {
    $("form").submit(function() { check(); return false; });
});` and then remove the `onclick = "check();"` from the `<input` element

Comment: @Occam'sRazor yeah I did the exact thing it is currently this
$(function() { $("form").submit(function() { check(); return false; }); });
and the input is:
<input id="button" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Check" ">

It's still refreshing the page whenever I press the button.

Comment: @NagaSaiA I added the check function